# How to find coordinates on a lenovo

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

A lot of good command block pros use coordinates, but my computer is a lenovo 2-in-1. How can I still check my coordinates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If <kbd>F3</kbd> does something else for your machine, <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> should do what <kbd>F3</kbd> usually does.

Answer (score -1):

Just press <kbd>F3</kbd> like you do on any other computer. If you have a keyboard, you should have it.